# r.patch results in a blank map in GRASS

Tags: raster, grass-gis, grass-7.0

I have a collection of tiles downloaded from the EDINA Digimap service, in `asc` format. I imported these into GRASS using the `r.in.gdal` function, and they appear in the display screen as expected.

I want to join these separate raster files together to create one continuous raster, however when I use the `r.patch` function, a map is created in the layer manager, and I get 100% completion, but nothing shows up in the display.

Any ideas how to correct this? Or a different function that is better suited?

Answer (score 3):

One suggestion would be to ensure that the computational region is correctly set, i.e.:

```
g.region rast=tile1,tile2,tile3,...,tilen -p
```

Then you should run the `r.patch` command:

```
r.patch input=tile1,tile2,tile3,...,tilen output=merged_raster
```

You should be able to display the merged raster in your GRASS monitor. If it is still blank, try passing `-z` to `r.patch`. Further details about the function [here](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.patch.html)